# PyQt5 call a function on Dialog resized

Tags: pyqt5

I have a `MainWindow` with a button, when I click the button, a dialog will pop up following the code below

```
self.window = QtWidgets.QDialog(None, QtCore.Qt.WindowSystemMenuHint|QtCore.Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint)
list_to_print = [1,2,3,4]
self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
self.ui.setupUi(self.window, list_to_print)
self.window.show()
```

My dialog is created from `QtDesigner` and `PyUIC`

```
Class Ui_Dialog(QtCore.QObject):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog, the_list):
        self.my_list = the_list
        ....
        # the UI is set here
        ....

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        ....

    def functionOnResize(self)
        print(self.my_list)
```

How can I call the `functionOnResize` when the dialog is resized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to attach the event to your method by doing this:

```
Class Ui_Dialog(QtCore.QObject):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog, the_list):
        self.my_list = the_list
        Dialog.resizeEvent = self.functionOnResize

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        ....

    def functionOnResize(self, event)
        print(self.my_list)
```